What is wrong in my argument for non-existence of amorphous set?
In ZF, it can be proved that amorphous set exists.
(It seems not easy, and I haven't tried to understand it)
In set theory, an amorphous set is an infinite set which is not the disjoint union of two infinite subsets.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set
But, where is the mistake for the argument for the theorem A?
Theorem A: Every infinite set is a union of two disjoint infinite subsets.
Let $X$ be any infinite set.
Infinite means not finite.
So there is no natural number $n$, such that there is a bijection between $X$ and $n$.
So there is
no bijection between $X$ and $\emptyset$,
so $X$ contains an element, denoted by $x_{1}$
no bijection between $X$ and $\{\emptyset\}$,
so $X$ contains an element other than $x_{1}$, denoted by $x_{2}$
no bijection between $X$ and $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$,
so $X$ contains an element other than $x_{1},x_{2}$ denoted by $x_{3}$,
no bijection between X and $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$
$\vdots$
so $X$ contains $x_{1},x_{2}, x_{3},x_{4}\ldots$
Now we define $Y=\{x_{1},x_{3},x_{5},x_{7},\ldots\}$ and $Z=X-Y$,
It is clear that $Y$ and $Z$ are infinite and disjoint.

"In ZF, it can be proved that amorphous set exist" - this is not true (otherwise ZFC would be inconsistent). Correct statement: "In ZF, it can't be proved that amorphous set doesn't exist".

What you wrote is not a proof, because proof is finite sequence of statements, and "..." in middle of your text is not a statement. Or, formulated otherwise, proof is finite sequence of statements, and your text is infinite. To formalize "take elements one by one" you need axiom of countable choice.

BTW, as stated, theorem A is valid (in ZF): just take the empty set and the whole set as disjoint sets. Or, if you don't want to allow the empty set, choose one element $x$ of the given set, and consider ${x}$ and $X \setminus {x}$.
Probably you wanted to say, "Every infinite set is a union of two disjoint infinite subsets".

Thank you Ulli, I fixed it.

Firstly, it is consistent that an amorphous set exists, but it is not provable. If it were provable from $\sf ZF$, then it would be provable from $\sf ZFC$, since you're just adding axioms, the previous proof remains valid. But we know that the Axiom of Choice proves that there are no amorphous sets.
Secondly, the problem is that a proof by induction (on the natural numbers) only tells you that for every $n<\omega$, there is a subset of size $n$. It does not, however, allow you to find a subset which is infinite. In fact, it does not even allow you to prove there is a family of sets $\{A_n\mid n<\omega\}$ such that $|A_n|=n$, and even if you could have proved that, you still couldn't prove the union of those sets is countably infinite without having chosen a way to enumerate each of them.
Your proof relies on the Axiom of Choice in choosing and naming the $x_n$ in a coherent and consistent way which allows you build the set $\{x_n\mid n<\omega\}$. If you look at the theorem about definition by recursion, you need to have a function $f\colon A\to A$, and then for every $a_0\in A$ there is a sequence such that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. But you are not specifying a function, you are, instead, specifying a pool of candidate and you're picking one from them in an arbitrary fashion. This can be made functional using the Axiom of Choice (by fixing a choice function and iterating it), but as written it is not functional, so the recursion theorem does not apply.

Thank you for precise answer! I used AC without realizing it was AC.
